# multiples section on Restplus swagger documentation

Tags: python, swagger, flask-restplus

On Restplus documentation (using B!ueprints) we see : a full example: https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/0.2.3/example.html

The created swagger documentation has only one section "todos : TODO operations "

How can I have multiples sections ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Namespaces to achieve this. Each Namespace becomes a separate section in swagger doc.

http://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scaling.html